# How do I pull elements out of an array and put it in a text field in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is just an exercise I'm trying to complete. I was thinking in terms of creating an order form in the most basic way. I have a basic array with a list of guitars. I would have a user put a number in the first field and that number would reference an index in a array to put the array element in another text box. This is what I have at this point-

```
var gbrand = ('Jackson', 'BC Rich', 'Gibson', 'Fender', 'Dean', 'ESP', 'Fernandez');

function ordernum(gbrand)
{

    var order = document.order.perchnumb.value 

    if ( order != '' )
    {

      order = gbrand[index];
      document.order.instrum.value = order;

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an Array. You have a bunch of string literal expressions, and you're only keeping the result of the last one: `'Fernandez'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I would say this should do the trick:

```
var gbrand = ['Jackson', 'BC Rich', 'Gibson', 'Fender', 'Dean', 'ESP', 'Fernandez'];

function ordernum(gbrand) {
    var orderId = document.order.perchnumb.value 

    if (orderId != '' && !isNaN(orderId)) {
      document.order.instrum.value = gbrand[orderId];
    }
}
```

If you leave your code like that, `var gbrand` will live in the global namespace, making it available to the function `ordernum` without actually passing it to the function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just forgot the `Array` constructor.

```
var gbrand = Array('Jackson',.....);
```

Or you can use an array literal (preferred):

```
var gbrand = ['Jackson',...];
```

Note the square brackets instead of the round parentheses.

Comment: argh... I'm a dork, can't believe I forgot to use brackets

Answer (score 1):

The array is constructed like Kolink notes:

```
var gbrand = ['Jackson', ...];
```

But there is a second problem with:

```
order = gbrand[index];
```

in that ode snippet index is undefined, modify it so:

```
order = gbrand[order];
```